# How to connect an email to the timeline of the activity of two entities?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I need the email to be visible in the activity for several entities.

I tried directly adding to the activityPointer object, but working with this activity is blocked.
Is it possible to somehow bind several regardingobjects to a email?
Or what other possible solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Multiple regarding object is not possible in any activity type
2. Adding directly in activity pointer table is unsupported
3. Email activity may show up in multiple contacts/accounts or email enabled entities timeline if they are added as recipients (to/cc) of email activity
4. Adding a custom additional lookup in email form to capture the additional regarding object and a custom connector can be developed to show it in timeline